# Iterating print() between classes

Tags: python

BlackJack game.
I have the following classes defined:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__(self):
        return ('{} of {},'
                .format(self.rank,self.suit))
```

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # starting with empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
    def deal(self):
        return self.deck.pop(0) //I'm dealing a card and taking
                                  him out of the deck
```

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []  //start with emptpy list and add Cards objects

    def add_card(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        for i in self.cards:
            return (f"{i}")
```

I'm creating a new deck, want to append to dealer's hand using the deal() method and to print the dealer's hand:

```
GameDeck = Deck()
DealerHand = Hand()
DealerHand.add_card(GameDeck.deal())
```

I'm printing the dealer's hand all good:

```
print(DealerHand)
```

**OUTPUT:** 5 of ♥

The problem starts when Im dealing another card from the deck:

```
DealerHand.add_card(GameDeck.deal())
print(DealerHand)
```

I'm getting the same result: 5 of ♥.

After debbuing it looks like self.hand (what I am trying to print) consists of 2 card classes (it's ok) but manages **to  print only the first one** because it's going back to the str method in the Card class and not moving to the second iterable i in self.cards list:

from Hand class, fails to move to the next i and print it

```
def __str__(self):
        for i in self.cards:
            return (f"{i}")
```

Any thoughts why it prints only the first object in self.cards list?

Comment: Because a `return` statement exits the function. Replace it with something like `return "\n".join(self.cards)`

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but I will throw it out as a design suggestion: Consider modifying the `__init__` method for the `Hand` class to take as a parameter a `Deck` instance and then let it `deal` to itself the necessary number of cards required to make up a hand. This would be better encapsulation for it should be the `Hand` class that enforces the rule of how many cards constitute a hand. You also no longer then need the `add_card` method.

Answer (score 2):

A `return` statement returns the given expression immediately, and therefore quits the function. Something like this will therefore not have the desired effect:

```
def __str__(self):
    for i in self.cards:
        return (f"{i}")
```

The `__str__` method needs to return a single string. If, for example, you want to return a string of the cards all on their own line, you can create that string first, and then return it:

```
def __str__(self):
    return_value = ""
    for card in self.cards:
        return_value += card + "\n"
```

Or join the cards with a single, idiomatic expression. `str.join` joins the given iterable of strings with a given string (in this case, a newline character: `\n`):

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(self.cards)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `__str__` function returns inside the for loop, which will terminate the loop after only one iteration. Instead, you want to return a string representation of the whole list of cards. Something like

```
def __str__(self):
    return ", ".join(self.cards)
```